# Celery накапливает периодические задания и выполняет пачкой

Tags: python, django, celery

Celery контролируется by superviser. Есть файл для celery и для beat, но запускаются 3 процесса (worker дублируется). В логах всегда фигурирует Worker-1.
**Есть выдержки из логов [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016685/celery-collects-tasks-instead-of-executing).**

Проблема заключается в том, что таски, выполняющиеся каждые 2 минуты, запускаются вовремя только первые 20-40 минут. Дальше все начинает идти не так. По прошествии очередных 2-х минут, задания перестают выполняться вовремя. Остаются только сообщение отправки

`Scheduler: Sending due task contestsapp.tasks.apply_votes`

без получения

`Received task: contestsapp.tasks.apply_votes[786b5cc6-5b08-40b0-9638-970a5ce6990f]`

Таким образом они накапливаются (неясно где, но celery процессы держат 90MB в памяти). Через некоторое время воркер хватает все невыполненные задания и мгновенно (они примитивные) выполняет.

В итоге задания с периодом 2 мин выполняются каждые 10 минут по 5 раз (показатели варьируются). Больше 5-ти одинаковых тасков не скапливается.

В остальном система работает. Отказов и исключений нет, брокер сбрасывался, база синхронизировалась, PeriodicTask.objects.update(last_run_at=None) не помог, TZ везде (даже ОС) стоит UTC.

PS
Иногда приходит пара десятков отложенных на дни-недели тасков. Такой "нагрузки" хрупкий баланс двухминуток обычно не выдерживает, и проявляется эта проблема (но и без них сценарий всегда один).

**Компоненты системы:**

- Rabbitmq - celery 3
- Apache2 - wsgi - Django 1.9.5
- Supervisor for celery and beat (but it runs one additional worker )

**Файл настроек:**

```
settings.py

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
```

**Пример задачи:**

```
@periodic_task(ignore_result=True, run_every=crontab(minute='*/2'))
def apply_denial():
    print('apply_denial')
    denialDicts =  {id:cache.get(id) for id in cache.keys("denial:*") if  cache.ttl(id)<=290}
    for k, v in denialDicts.items():
        user = Profile.objects.get(id=k[(k.index('denial:') + 7):])
        user.denial = (list(set(v) - set(user.denial)) + user.denial)[:300]
        user.save()
        cache.delete(k)
```

Копал уже во все стороны...

Comment: Вы пробовали сменить брокер с RabbitMQ на Redis, например?

Comment: Редис стоит для кэша, но нет. Попробую, чтобы исключить брокера как причину. Но обычно ставят rmq в связку с celery и все в порядке, хотелось разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

А вы урл брокера задали???

Типа
`BROKER_URL = "amqp://user:pass@localhost/queue"`,

где `user` и `pass` это логин пароль от раббита, а `queue` - очередь куда пуляются ваши сообщения

**P.S** если так запускаете воркеры

```
-A project worker --loglevel=INFO
-A project worker --loglevel=INFO
-A project beat --loglevel=INFO
```

попробуйте заменить на:

```
-A app_celery worker -l info -B -Q "наименование очереди"
```

если никакую очередь явно не используете то `-Q` не нужно указывать